# Azure Devops Pipelline Jekyll Build Failure

Tags: azure-devops, jekyll

I'm using a Azure Devops Pipeline to build my Jekyll Blog Site and to publish it to Azure Blob Storage. It has of late been working OK, but I did a new post today and it failed in the Build step. All worked Ok a day or so ago. Nb: The build is triggered by a commit to to the Devops repository.  The site built OK locally.

```
Generating script.
Script contents:
bundle exec jekyll build
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
"C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe" /D /E:ON /V:OFF /S /C "CALL "D:\a\_temp\3f5d7781-f35f-48db-b750-9feccaae9bb5.cmd""
C:/hostedtoolcache/windows/Ruby/3.0.0/x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/kramdown-1.17.0/lib/kramdown/parser/html.rb:10:in `require': cannot load such file -- rexml/parsers/baseparser (LoadError)
from C:/hostedtoolcache/windows/Ruby/3.0.0/x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/kramdown-1.17.0/lib/kramdown/parser/html.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
from C:/hostedtoolcache/windows/Ruby/3.0.0/x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/kramdown-1.17.0/lib/kramdown/parser/kramdown/html.rb:10:in `require'
from C:/hostedtoolcache/windows/Ruby/3.0.0/x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/kramdown-1.17.0/lib/kramdown/parser/kramdown/html.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
from C:/hostedtoolcache/windows/Ruby/3.0.0/x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/kramdown-1.17.0/lib/kramdown/parser/kramdown/paragraph.rb:14:in `require'
from C:/hostedtoolcache/windows/Ruby/3.0.0/x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/kramdown-1.17.0/lib/kramdown/parser/kramdown/paragraph.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
from C:/hostedtoolcache/windows/Ruby/3.0.0/x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/kramdown-1.17.0/lib/kramdown/parser/kramdown.rb:345:in `require'
from C:/hostedtoolcache/windows/Ruby/3.0.0/x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/kramdown-1.17.0/lib/kramdown/parser/kramdown.rb:345:in `<class:Kramdown>'
from C:/hostedtoolcache/windows/Ruby/3.0.0/x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/kramdown-1.17.0/lib/kramdown/parser/kramdown.rb:60:in `<module:Parser>'
from C:/hostedtoolcache/windows/Ruby/3.0.0/x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/kramdown-1.17.0/lib/kramdown/parser/kramdown.rb:19:in `<module:Kramdown>'
from C:/hostedtoolcache/windows/Ruby/3.0.0/x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/kramdown-1.17.0/lib/kramdown/parser/kramdown.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
from C:/hostedtoolcache/windows/Ruby/3.0.0/x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-3.8.7/lib/jekyll/converters/smartypants.rb:3:in `require'
from C:/hostedtoolcache/windows/Ruby/3.0.0/x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-3.8.7/lib/jekyll/converters/smartypants.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
from C:/hostedtoolcache/windows/Ruby/3.0.0/x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-3.8.7/lib/jekyll.rb:13:in `require'
from C:/hostedtoolcache/windows/Ruby/3.0.0/x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-3.8.7/lib/jekyll.rb:13:in `block in require_all'
from C:/hostedtoolcache/windows/Ruby/3.0.0/x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-3.8.7/lib/jekyll.rb:12:in `each'
from C:/hostedtoolcache/windows/Ruby/3.0.0/x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-3.8.7/lib/jekyll.rb:12:in `require_all'
from C:/hostedtoolcache/windows/Ruby/3.0.0/x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-3.8.7/lib/jekyll.rb:194:in `<top (required)>'
from C:/hostedtoolcache/windows/Ruby/3.0.0/x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-3.8.7/exe/jekyll:8:in `require'
from C:/hostedtoolcache/windows/Ruby/3.0.0/x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-3.8.7/exe/jekyll:8:in `<top (required)>'
from C:/hostedtoolcache/windows/Ruby/3.0.0/x64/bin/jekyll:23:in `load'
from C:/hostedtoolcache/windows/Ruby/3.0.0/x64/bin/jekyll:23:in `<main>'
##[error]Cmd.exe exited with code '1'.
Finishing: Build
```

I removed the post and recommited and it still failed.

***The Build script in the Pipeine is:***

```
bundle exec jekyll build
```

**My gemfile follows**

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

# Hello! This is where you manage which Jekyll version is used to run.
# When you want to use a different version, change it below, save the
# file and run `bundle install`. Run Jekyll with `bundle exec`, like so:
#
#     bundle exec jekyll serve
#
# This will help ensure the proper Jekyll version is running.
# Happy Jekylling!
gem "jekyll", "~> 3.8.5"

# This is the default theme for new Jekyll sites. You may change this to anything you like.
# gem "minima", "~> 2.0"

# If you want to use GitHub Pages, remove the "gem "jekyll"" above and
# uncomment the line below. To upgrade, run `bundle update github-pages`.
# gem "github-pages", group: :jekyll_plugins

# If you have any plugins, put them here!
group :jekyll_plugins do
  gem "jekyll-feed", "~> 0.6"
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem "tzinfo-data", platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

# Performance-booster for watching directories on Windows
gem "wdm", "~> 0.1.0" if Gem.win_platform?

# https://github.com/pmarsceill/just-the-docs
# gem "just-the-docs"

# https://github.com/pages-themes/leap-day
gem "jekyll-theme-leap-day"

# https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-seo-tag
gem 'jekyll-seo-tag'
gem 'jekyll-paginate'

# https://www.r-bloggers.com/creating-an-rss-feed-to-add-your-jekyll-github-pages-blog-to-r-bloggers/#:~:text=%20Creating%20an%20RSS%20Feed%20to%20Add%20Your,put%20the%20.xml%20file%20in%20the...%20More%20
# gem 'jekyll-feed'

gem "webrick"
```

**The pipeline scripts:**

```
Pipeline: Agent pool: Hosted VS2017
Get Resources: The repository, Master Branch, also tried a branch gleaned for earlier submit. Clean:False
Use Ruby>-2.4: Version Spec >=2.4  AddToPath is checked
Install Jekyll and bundler: gem install jekyll bundler
Install Gems: bundle install
Build: bundle exec jekyll build

Following steps are Copy Site and Publish Artifact
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I played around with the Ruby Version.  Found if I set that script Version Spec to:

```
<3.0
```

it worked!  :)

Comment: You should also be able to specify one of the specific versions it supports (such as 2.7.2 or 2.6.6) to eliminate the issue. This has the benefit of clearly defining which version is being used for your builds in the future.

Comment: Indeed, it seems the issue about Ruby 3.0, but I am not sure about it. https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/8523

Comment: Nb: I got a rejection if I set a specific version. Ruby 3 leaves out a number of gems, hence the issue.

Answer (score 1):

> Azure Devops Pipelline Jekyll Build Failure

If you are using the private agent, please try to following steps to resolve this error:

- Running `bundle info kramdown` will give you the path to where `kramdown`
  has been installed.
- Run `gem env` to get an insight on all paths Ruby is concerned about.
- If **the directory** where `kramdown` got installed from above isn't listed
  in the `gem env` output, you'll have to manually add that path

If you are using the hosted agent, please try to reference following suggestions：

Add gem "`webrick`" to the `Gemfile` in your website. Than run `bundle install`

At this point you can run `bundle exec jekyll build`

Comment: I've added my gemfile as above, including gem "webrick" at the bottom. I did bundle install locally then posted sent the project to Azure Devops again. Problem isn't resolved.  I guess I'm using a Hosted Agent as its sets up everything  in Azure(installs etc) before the build.

Comment: @DavidJones, It is indeed possible, how about the result when you use private agent?

Comment: Just checked, am using Hosted Agent. Don't now how to do i it as a private agent.

Comment: Adding other scripts in pipeline to original psot.

Comment: Tried a switch to Azure Pipelines - Windows 2019 , same outcome.

Comment: Nb: Its using: Found tool in cache: Ruby 3.0.0 x64

Comment: @DavidJones,please refer this document to create your private agent: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops and have you tried with Azure Pipelines - vs2017-win2016?