Azure Devops Jekyll site build fails, worked previously
My blog site https://davidjones.sportronics.com.au
I submit to Azure Devops where it is built as a Jekyll site.
Has worked fine for a several years with only minor updates.
Scripts run using Win 2019 VM.
Yesterday the build failed:
Pipeline steps:

Use Ruby > 3.0.0
Install Jekyll and Bundler
Install Gems
Build
Copy site to staging directory
Publish Artifact: _site

Pipeline step: Use Ruby > 3.0.0
Script: Version Spec 3.1.4
Was this (this worked for some time) but failed today.
Devops says available versions are 3.0.7 or 3.1.5
Worked on previous submission mid May and for a long time prior.
Tried Version specs as below but fails at Build

3.1.5
3.0.7
> 3.0.0
Fir this: Found tool in cache: Ruby 3.1.5 x64

Nb: Local build uses 3.2.2
With these, got past the version check runs next 2 steps OK but build fails:
C:/hostedtoolcache/windows/Ruby/3.1.5/x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/csv/parser.rb:3:in `require': 126: The specified module could not be found. 

Install Jekyll and bundler:
Script:gem install jekyll bundler
Final lines:
Done installing documentation for bundler after 0 seconds
29 gems installed
Finishing: Install Jekyll and bundler

Install Gems
Script: bundle install
Final Lines:
Bundle complete! 10 Gemfile dependencies, 43 gems now installed.
Use `bundle info [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
Finishing: Install Gems

Build:
Script: bundle exec jekyll build
Output:
Starting: Build
==============================================================================
Task         : Command line
Description  : Run a command line script using Bash on Linux and macOS and cmd.exe on Windows
Version      : 2.237.1
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line
==============================================================================
Generating script.
Script contents: shell
bundle exec jekyll build
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
"C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe" /D /E:ON /V:OFF /S /C "CALL "D:\a\_temp\9815d7ee-08b2-4491-934a-b1fb6ffcea97.cmd""
C:/hostedtoolcache/windows/Ruby/3.1.5/x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/csv/parser.rb:3:in `require': 126: The specified module could not be found.   - C:/hostedtoolcache/windows/Ruby/3.1.5/x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/strscan-3.1.0/lib/strscan.so (LoadError)
    from C:/hostedtoolcache/windows/Ruby/3.1.5/x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/csv/parser.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/hostedtoolcache/windows/Ruby/3.1.5/x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/csv.rb:98:in `require_relative'
    from C:/hostedtoolcache/windows/Ruby/3.1.5/x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/csv.rb:98:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/hostedtoolcache/windows/Ruby/3.1.5/x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/jekyll-4.3.3/lib/jekyll.rb:28:in `require'
    from C:/hostedtoolcache/windows/Ruby/3.1.5/x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/jekyll-4.3.3/lib/jekyll.rb:28:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/hostedtoolcache/windows/Ruby/3.1.5/x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/jekyll-4.3.3/exe/jekyll:8:in `require'
    from C:/hostedtoolcache/windows/Ruby/3.1.5/x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/jekyll-4.3.3/exe/jekyll:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/hostedtoolcache/windows/Ruby/3.1.5/x64/bin/jekyll:32:in `load'
    from C:/hostedtoolcache/windows/Ruby/3.1.5/x64/bin/jekyll:32:in `<main>'
##[error]Cmd.exe exited with code '1'.
Finishing: Build


I have posted a detailed blog on this: Azure Pipelines: Jekyll Site Build failure


I did meet a similar problem 3+ years ago:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66131604/azure-devops-pipelline-jekyll-build-failure

Why in about 20 days should the 3.14 Ruby version suddenly not work? Nothing changed as far as the DevOps scripts go.
Nb: The blog site was configured following the method  here:
https://www.forevolve.com/en/articles/2018/07/10/how-to-deploy-and-host-a-jekyll-website-in-azure-blob-storage-using-a-vsts-continuous-deployment-pipeline-part-2/

Futher:  Ruby is preinstalled on Microsoft-hosted agents in Azure Pipelines]:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/ruby?view=azure-devops
And only 2 versions available 3.0.7 and 3.1.5. Seems can't use other versions without some kind of install step in the pipeline
So do need to get the pipeline running with one of these. So need to resolve why the build falls over.

Just created a new Azure Devops pipeline as previous but Build step fails as previous too. SOMETHING DEFINITELY HAS CHANGED AT THE AZURE END!  :(

Ruby 3.1.5 Released:
Posted by hsbt on 23 Apr 2024

In Installing Gems:
...
Fetching strscan 3.1.0
...
Installing strscan 3.1.0 with native extensions
...
But in the Build:
C:/hostedtoolcache/windows/Ruby/3.1.5/x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/csv/parser.rb:3:in `require': 126:
The specified module could not be found.

C:/hostedtoolcache/windows/Ruby/3.1.5/x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/strscan-3.1.0/lib/strscan.so (LoadError)

Appears the missing file would have been created so probably is path issue.

Directory of C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Ruby\3.1.5\x64\lib\ruby\gems\3.1.0\gems\strscan-3.1.0\lib  =          32,256 strscan.so
So the file IS there but fails to load! That IS the issue!

I can confirm that the issue indeed exists in the windows-2019 agent in Azure Pipeline. The issue is from the agent image configuration itself. You can report the issue here:  https://github.com/actions/runner-images/issues And I have added an answer to share the methods to solve the issue. You can check it.

I can reproduce the same issue when using the Microsoft-hosted agent: Windows-2019 in Azure Pipeline.

The cause of the issue could be that the environment settings or the configurations have issues when using the Ruby version 3.1.5 on Windows-2019 agent. You can report the issue to this feedback site:  Agent image feedback
To solve this issue, you can refer to the following methods:
Method1: You can change to use the Ruby version: 3.0.7 in Windows-2019 agent.
For example:
- task: UseRubyVersion@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '3.0.7'

Method2: You can re-install Ruby version 3.1.5 or other versions in Pipeline with the script. Then the pipeline can run successfully.
Here is an example:
pool:
  vmImage: windows-2019

steps:

- script:  choco install ruby --version=3.1.5.1
- script: |
    gem install jekyll bundler
 
  displayName: Install Jekyll and bundler

- script: 
     bundle install
  displayName: Install Gems
  


- script: 'bundle exec jekyll build'
  displayName: Build

Result:

Method3: You can change to use Microsoft-hosted agent: image Ububtu- 20.04, Ububtu-22.04.
For example:
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

Update:
@David Jones has posted the issue report ticket: Using the Ruby version 3.1.5 on Windows-2019 Agent failure. We can keep focus on the feedback from image management team.

First Try: Use 3.0.7
Fail on Install Gems
Installing jekyll-theme-leap-day 0.2.0
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

@DavidJones The setting can work fine in my pipeline. You can try other methods and check if it can work for you. If they have the same issue, you can share the current YAML pipeline definition and Gem File setting. Then I will do further investigation.

Method 2 Got similar error:
Fetching minima 2.5.1
Installing minima 2.5.1
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
PS Thx for your help Kevin

@DavidJones Can you share more details about the new error? Can you help us confirm if it can work fine on your local machine ? If yes, can you share the ruby version on your local machine ?

Method 3 Worked! :) Now to check blog site content.

@DavidJones Feel free to share the result with us : )

@DavidJones I can confirm that the issue is from the image itself. You can use the workaround for the time being. And I suggest that you can report the issue to this site:  https://github.com/actions/runner-images/issues The managers of the agent image can help you solve the issue from the image itself.

Posted issue: https://github.com/actions/runner-images/issues/9999

I have now concluded my examination of this issue. I ended up using a Ubuntu Azure Host Agent pipeline. This is discussed in two parts on my blog site:
https://davidjones.sportronics.com.au/web/Azure_Pipelines-Jekyll_Site_Build_failure-web.html
and
https://davidjones.sportronics.com.au/web/Azure_Pipelines-Jekyll_Site_Build_failure-Part_2-web.html

I have now concluded my examination of this issue.
I ended up using a Ubuntu Azure Host Agent pipeline.
This is discussed in two parts on my blog site:

Azure_Pipelines Jekyll Site Build Failure Part 1 and
Azure_Pipelines Jekyll Site Build Failure Part 2

